# Which components are required to connect a display to the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: display

I have Raspberry Pi 2, HDMI cable and a 7'' display called `at070tn92` from an old android tablet.

I want to know what other components should I order in order to connect that display and make it working.
Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

**Please dont mark this as off-topic**
I need help to connect display to thw Raspberry Pi and I don't know what components I will need. I don't want exact name of component, their model name or brand to buy but general names. For example, I don't want to know which brand cable but if it should be HDMI or VGA, besides cable what other component I need, etc.

Comment: Apprarently you need a driver board, an AC adapter to power it, and just plug the hdmi cable on the input. I'm assuming you have somethin like this...: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Diy-Monitor-for-Raspberry-Pi-HDMI-VGA-2AV-Lcd-Driver-7-AT070TN92-Touch-Screen-/121119934991

Comment: @Elric can you please mention it in answer, along with link to each component separately?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because purchasing recommendations are considered off-topic.

Comment: @Ghanima why off-topic? I need help with raspberry pi.  I don't want exact name of component to buy but general names. for example, I dont want to know which brand cable I want but should it be hdmi or vga, stuff like this

Comment: @edward torvalds , can't you just take a photography of the components you have and upload this photo to imgur so we can know what you have and what you don't have yet?

Comment: @Elric right now I just have the [display (you can search but its name)](http://i00.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/367/796/461/461796367_232.JPG). I have ordered raspberry pi 2 and it comes with hdmi cable. [List of all components it comes with](http://www.amazon.in/Raspberry-Pi-Model-Complete-enclosure/dp/B00U4VCOHC/ref=pd_sim_sbs_147_5?ie=UTF8&dpID=414xHj15YjL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=12VNMZV3GBHS64JYSDFB)

Answer (score -4):

## Finding the components

I do not know how to do this on a display from an Android tablet, but you can use pretty much any TV (yes, old or new) as long as it has an HDMI socket.

**You will need:**

- An HDMI cable
- A display the fits the above requirements
- A mobile phone charger
- A MicroSD Card (at least 4GB) with the Raspian OS installed on it ([raspberrypi.org/downloads](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/))

Once you've got all of them, we can proceed on to the next step.

## Connecting the components

First, insert one end of the HDMI cable into the HDMI socket on the Pi, and the other end into the HDMI socket on the TV. Next, put the SD Card in the back of the Pi (it is a push-click one for in and out). This holds what the Raspberry Pi runs on, and also all your files. Finally, connect the mobile phone charger to a mains electricity plug and the Raspberry Pi. ***Note: Not all phone chargers work, only USB Plug-MicroUSB chargers. If you're not sure which one your's is, look online for exact specification.***

I really hope that this helps you.

Comment: So basically all your answer says is: Plug an HDMI display into the HDMI port of the RPi ... I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: How does the SD card and micro USB charger help matters?